# CSS select element within multiple imbricated classes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a html page that contains a structure like this:

```
<table class="pick">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="class1">
                <div class="class2">
                    <div class="myClass"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="class1">
                    <div class="myClass"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

how can I select the elements that are inside the element with `myClass` class which is inside the `pick` class, but the structure of the `div` elements is variable, as in the code example?

I probably need something like this: `.pick .something_else .myClass { /*style*/ }` but I don't know exactly what.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.pick .myClass { /* style */ }` will do the job. There is no need to add all the classes till the one you wish to select.